# When using geom_smooth to plot a best fit line I get: `stat_smooth()`: invalid 'x' type in 'x || y' in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, linear-regression

I am currently trying to create a scatterplot with a best-fit line.

```
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(y = d_emp, x=d_gdp)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = "FALSE")
```

However, I keep getting the following error message:

> Computation failed in `stat_smooth()`: invalid 'x' type in 'x || y'

**The scatterplot works perfectly, it is only the best fit line that does not show (so the geom_smooth part).**

[image]

Here is what my dataset looks like:

[image: My data]

Comment: Images are not a good way for posting data (or code). See [this Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/8245406) and a [relevant xkcd](https://xkcd.com/2116/). Can you post sample data in `dput` format? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(df)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You provided a string to the boolean argument `se`. This should work

```
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(y = d_emp, x = d_gdp)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE)
```